# Virtual Memory Address in Binary form

Tags: operating-system, virtual-memory

Please help me out, im studying operating systems. under virtual memory i found this:
A user process generates a virtual address 11123456. and it is said the virtual address in  binary form is 0001 0001 0001 0010 0011 0100 0101 0110. how was that converted because when i convert 11123456 to bin i get 0001 0101 0011 0111 0110 000 0000. it is said The virtual memory is implemented by paging, and the page size is 4096 bytes

Comment: How are you converting this?

Comment: I used a calculator, windows calculator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You assume that 11123456 is a decimal number, while according to the result it's hexadecimal. In general, decimal numbers are rarely used in CS, representation in orders of 2 is much more common and convenient. Today mostly used are base 16 (hexadecimal) and 2 (binary).

Comment: Thank you very much, i tried it in octal thinking maybe. i never thought about hex since the number was too long i thought it will be dec, if hex i expected some alphabets there, thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Converting into binary may help to identify the page number and offset so that you can calculate the physical address corresponding to the logical address. It should be good if you can understand how to do this if you are CS student.

For the particular problem, i.e. paging, you can convert from logical to physical address without converting into binary using modulo (%) and divide (/) operators. However, doing things in binary is original way for this.

In your question, the value 11123456 should be a hexadecimal number and it should be written as 0x11123456 to distinguish with the decimal numbers. And from the binary format "0001 0001 0001 0010 0011 0100 0101 0110", we can infer that the offset of the logical address is "0100 0101 0110" (12 rightmost bits, or 132182 in decimal, or 0x20456 in hexadecimal) and the page number is "0001 0001 0001 0010 0011" (the rest bits, 69923 in decimal, or 0x11123 in hexadecimal).